# Combine Local Disk to another hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata

I have a 150gb local disk on my Windows 7 x64 ultimate computer,
i recently bought another 150gb hard drive and wish to merge/combine the 2 together to form 1 300gb hard drive.

Is this possible to do without losing all the data on it?

And i have thought about RAID but was curious if there was a faster easier option before i go ahead and take my pc apart

Comment: and the last sentance has me confused, what did you mean? SATA has nothing to do with merge/combine drives.  Did you mean RAID.

Comment: This has been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-RAID option is to mount the second HDD as a junction in the first HDD.

To do this, create an empty folder on the first HDD and the, in Disk Management, assign the second drive to the empty folder instead of assigning it a drive letter.

This is a very simple way to do it but you only get the additional capacity *with* that particular folder.

Answer (score 2):

Not without losing all data. What you should do with the drives is back them up, then set them up in what is known as RAID 0. This will make them show up as one 300GB drive to the system. If this is the drive you have windows installed to, then you'll need to set this up in the BIOS of your motherboard so that when you reinstall windows, the installer will see it as a second drive. Otherwise you can use the software RAID support built into windows.

Answer (score 1):

or if you just interested in more capacity, mount the second drive as a directory on the 1st drive.